# How can i change order of widget in layout by drag and drop with the mouse?

Tags: qt, layout, widget

I make my own class from `QWidget` with redefine of `paintEvent()`, `mousePressEvent()`, `mouseReleaseEvent()` and `mouseMoveEvent()`. All that methods for move widgets over other widget (yellow).

When i create my widgets in a layout, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I move black widget to the bottom and red to the top like this:

[image]

and resize window, all widgets refresh to their align positions:

[image]

But i want, when i move one widget higher then another, the widgets should align in layout in new places, like this:

[image]

Which function i should redefine to do it?

P.S. 
[There is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010835/how-to-programmatically-change-the-order-of-widgets-in-a-layout) a piece of code, that can move widgets positions inside layout (change their indexes), but i don't know how find out their (x,y) position to calculate new indexes in layout. I think, that i can do it in `resizeEvent()`. 
But it when it event was emitted, positions already changed to old. (like before moveing on 1 picture), and i need positions after moveing (like on secon picture). How can i get position of widget before it will be aligned?
or How can i change order of widget in layout by drag and drop with the mouse?

Comment: Please format your question properly and work on the sentence structure especially in your *P.S.* at the bottom. Personally I have no idea what you mean by "In `resizeEvent()` i got new position yet" especially after another peculiar piece of text: "but i don't know how know their positions". I will format your images but the rest is up to you.

Comment: Btw if your widgets look the way they do in your images I would suggest using `QGraphicsScene` with `QGraphicsProxyWidget` where you can set the `z value` which determines which item overlaps which.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I change my question. Is it still unclear?

Comment: You can always use some class member variables to store the positions of your widgets. So every time you capture a `resize event` you will have both the new and the old values at your disposal. As mentioned in my previous comment what you are doing seems a lot like a job for `QGraphicsScene`. If you still don't want to use it you have to enable each of your widgets to be draggable (see the `dragEnterEvent` and relative functions part of `QWidget`) as well as being able to accept drops (see `acceptDrops` and `dropEvent` - again part of `QWidget`).

Comment: @rbaleksandar
I want do something like dragable, aligned widgets on layout.
Like icons in Android menu, when you do long tap, and then you can move you icon in new place, when you drop it (release tap) icon change it position and all other icons aligned related to all changes.

What is the best way to do it? What kind of request to Google i need to do, to get some info about what i want?

Comment: I would still go for a `QGraphicsScene`. Each icon can be a custom `QGraphicsItem` that you can move around in a grid (that functionality you have to implement yourself) and also send updates on the rest. Each icon can be attached to a widget which you can then show after the activation of the icon in another view (for example swap the layout that contains the `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` with another one that contains the specific widget or use a tabbed widget (not that good omho for this scenario)).

Comment: @rbaleksandar where i can get examples of this `QGraphicsScene` using?

Comment: Start with the Qt documentation on it and from there go through the Qt's official examples with `QGraphicsScene` and just google for further tutorials and samples if that's not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write my own widget, then redefine following methods: `mouseReleaseEvent(), paintEvent(), mousePressEvent(), mouseMoveEvent()`. In `mousePressEvent()` I hold old X and Y positions and mouse position on figure. Then in `mouseMoveEvent()` i calculate if minimum distance of mouse move is riched and move widget to new position (it not moves widget index in layout). After it, if emitted `mouseReleaseEvent()` i just calculate new index of moving widget and change and update parent layout. If widget moves less then it height, then layout just updates without changing widget index.

```
void SimpleWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
        return;
    if (!IsMinimumDistanceRiched(event))
    {
        return;
    }
    int y = event->globalY() - mouseClickY + oldY;
    int BottomBorder = parentWidget->geometry().height() - this->geometry().height();
    if(y < 0) y = 0;
    else if(y > BottomBorder) y = BottomBorder;
    move(oldX, y);
}

void SimpleWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
        dragStartPosition = event->pos();
    oldX = this->geometry().x();
    oldY = this->geometry().y();
    mouseClickX = event->globalX();
    mouseClickY = event->globalY();
}

bool SimpleWidget::IsMinimumDistanceRiched(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    return (event->pos() - dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() >= QApplication::startDragDistance();
}

bool SimpleWidget::moveInLayout(QWidget *widget, MoveDirection direction)
{
    QVBoxLayout* myLayout = qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(widget->parentWidget()->layout());

    const int index = myLayout->indexOf(widget);
    if (direction == MoveUp && index == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (direction == MoveDown && index == myLayout->count()-1 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    const int newIndex = direction == MoveUp ? index - 1 : index + 1;
    myLayout->removeWidget(widget);
    myLayout->insertWidget(newIndex , widget);
    return true;
}

void SimpleWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption o;
    o.initFrom(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &o, &p, this);
}

void SimpleWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    int y = geometry().y();
    MoveDirection direct;
    int offset;
    if(oldY > y)
    {
        offset = oldY - y;
        direct = MoveUp;
    }
    else if(oldY < y)
    {
        offset = y - oldY;
        direct = MoveDown;
    }
    int count = offset/height();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        moveInLayout(this, direct);
    }
    update();
    QVBoxLayout* myLayout = qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(this->parentWidget->layout());
    myLayout->update();
    this->saveGeometry();
}
```